# grep multiple patterns and print results with the match pattern

Tags: grep

I'm looking to grep multiple files with multiple values.
*For example*: `grep -f filename.txt /home/* -R`
(filename.txt contains multiple values)

But, I need the know which file contained which value.
*For example*: /home/blah.txt contains value1, /home/aaa.txt contains value2, etc.

any suggestions?

Comment: doesn't grep add file prefix when more than one file is given as input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using some of the flags provided by `grep`.

You can try the following command :

`grep -R -f filename.txt /home/*` will search any pattern inside your `filename.txt` file and match it recursively against all files inside your home folder. You'll get an output like this :

```
#here my filename contains the entries bash and Bingo
$grep -R -f filename.txt /home/*
/home/user/.bash_history:vi .bashrc
/home/user/.bash_history:vi .bashrc
/home/user/.bash_history:awk -v RS=END_WORD '/Bingo1/ && /Bingo2/' test2.txt | grep -o 'Pokeman.*'
```

`grep` will output the file name and the full line containing your pattern.

If you only want to display the pattern that was found, try the following command :

```
#here the -o flag only displays the matched values, and -n adds the line number
$grep -R -o -n -f test /home/*
/home/user/.bash_history:128:bash
/home/user/.bash_history:156:bash
/home/user/.bash_history:193:Bingo
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your situation:

```
grep -HRnF '<pattern>' . --include "<file_name>"
```

So to search for the word 'test' in all file ending with .txt use something like:

```
grep -HRnF 'test' . --include "*.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU `grep` has option `-o`:

> -o, --only-matching
>
> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

So this should do what you want

```
grep -f filename.txt -R -H -o /home/*
```

Note I've also added `-H` (-with-filename) to print the filename always.

Comment: Ooops, thx, edited.