# Search for 2 strings in a file and output the line(s) containing both the strings

Tags: shell-script, grep

So I want to pass 2 strings and filename from the command line and search for both the strings in the file. 
Sample input : `script.sh file.txt AB 78`
Sample output : `001,AB,cse,78`

(where the file has this line among others that do not match)

My try:

```
`#/usr/bin/env bash`  
`grep '$2.*$3\|$3.*$2' $1`
```

However this doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep multiple patterns and print results with the match pattern](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319511/grep-multiple-patterns-and-print-results-with-the-match-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change you single quote into double quotes to allow the `$2` and `$3` to be expanded into your search string:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
grep "$2.*$3\|$3.*$2" $1
```

A better explanation is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash#6697781